# How to Query from salesforce the OpportunityFieldHistory with python

Tags: python, salesforce

I am having an issue figuring out how to start a query on the OpportunityFieldHistory from Salesforce.

The code I usually use and works for querying Opportunty or Leads work fine, but I do not know how should be written for the FieldHistory.

When I want to query the opportunity or Lead I use the following:

```
oppty1 = sf.opportunity.get('00658000002vFo3')
lead1 = sf.lead.get('00658000002vFo3')
```

and then do the proper query code with the access codes...

The problem arises when I want to do the analysis on the OpportunityFieldHistory, I tried the following:

```
opptyhist = sf.opportunityfieldhistory.get('xxx')
```

Guess what, does not work. Do you have any clue on what should I write between sf. and .get?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Python API are you using? `simple-salesforce`?

Comment: yes, simple-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [simple-salesforce API](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py), it appears that the `get` method accepts an ID which you are passing correctly. However, a quick search in the [Salesforce API reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BM7IAM) seems to indicate that the OpportunityFieldHistory may need to be obtained by another function such as `get_by_custom_id(self, custom_id_field, custom_id)`.

> ```
>   (OpportunityFieldHistory){
>      Id = None
>      CreatedDate = 2012-08-27 12:00:03
>      Field = "StageName"
>      NewValue = "3.0 - Presentation & Demo"
>      OldValue = "2.0 - Qualification & Discovery"
>      OpportunityId = "0067000000RFCDkAAP"
>   },
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did not get what I should exactly write in order to get the opp.ty field history.
What should I put in this: get_by_custom_id(self, custom_id_field, custom_id). ?

Comment: @Bostan I would guess something like `get_by_custom_id('OpportunityID', '00658000002vFo3')` may work if I am understanding the reference correctly.